# Use Apache (.htaccess) rules to use subdirectory instead and return specific file by default

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to set up a series of .htacces rules that work like this. My .htacces is inside the doc root.

1. rewrite the uri (internally) to be relative to a subdirectory
2. if the resource doesn't exist return a 200 with a specific file.

Here's what I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond /some/path/%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /some/path/index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/some/path
RewriteRule (.*) /some/path/$1 [L]
```

This causes my Apache server to return errors. I understand this is wrong but I don't know why. I've been researching this for a few hours. Also if there's a cleaner way I can do this please let me know, ty!

To clarify the second rewrite pair works by itself (when it comes to using the subdirectory), it's when used in combination with the first pair (using a file by default) that if fails. Also I don't want to use ErrorDocument because it must return a 200 in the missing file case

Comment: _"This causes my Apache server to return errors."_ - what errors?

Comment: _"Also I don't want to use ErrorDocument because it must return a 200 in the missing file case"_ - your error document could simply be a _script_, that sets the status code itself. That would still cause lots of 404 entries in the log though I suppose, but you could use [`FallbackResource`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource) instead. If you rewrite your request to `/some/path/` internally, and then let the FallbackRessource take over, I think that should work.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteCond /some/path/%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
> RewriteRule ^ /some/path/index.html [L]
> ```

This *condition* will always be successful (`/some/path/%{REQUEST_URI}` will never map to a file since you need to be testing an absolute file-path here, not a URL-path), so the request is always rewritten to `/some/path/index.html`.

Try the following instead (in the root `.htaccess` file):

```
RewriteEngine on

# Stop early if already rewritten to path
RewriteRule ^some/path(/|$) - [L]

# Test if the requested resource exists at "/some/path/..."
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/some/path%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^ some/path/index.html [L]

# Rewrite everything to "/some/path/..."
RewriteRule (.*) some/path/$1 [L]
```

Note that, with the current rules, any files outside of `/some/path/` will not be accessible. (Unless perhaps you have additional `.htaccess` files in those directories that should be accessible?)

Comment: I'm getting a similar error as before `Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.`

Comment: @rubixibuc You need to check the server's error log for the details of this error. A "500 Internal Server Error" is just a generic response that something went badly wrong. Are these all the directives you have in the `.htaccess` file? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files? Is mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: @rubixibuc I've updated my answer with a minor code improvement. This is really just an optimisation, so it shouldn't actually make any difference with regards to the error.

Comment: So your example is looping as well, because it checks if the path exists and then rewrites /repo/dist/index and then checks if repo/dist/repo/dist/index etc.

Comment: @rubixibuc I've updated my answer to fix the "looping" issue. That "optimisation" is actually required - but I've changed that and the last rule.

Comment: That first rule breaks the logic because it's saying if it matches some/path just stop, but it also needs to check if the the file doesn't exist

Comment: @rubixibuc Yes, but presumably you are not requesting `/some/path/…` directly, so on the first pass it doesn’t apply and the second rule is processed…

Comment: This does't exactly accomplish what I want, but I appreciate the suggestion. some/path/some/path could technically be valid from the doc root. I took some things from you example and a comment above to come up with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/some/path($|/)
RewriteRule (.*) /some/path/$1 [QSA,L]

FallbackResource /some/path/index.html` which works fine

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up going with. I ended up modifying the post virtual hosts include in Apache, and added something like this:

```
<Directory "/home/*/somepath/*"> 
  RewriteEngine on 

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/.well-known/
  RewriteRule !/dist/ /dist%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

  Redirect 404 /robots.txt
  FallbackResource /dist/index.html 
</Directory>
```